# Abrir extensión con aplicación y mostrar en textbox

Tags: vb.net

Estoy creando un "bloc de notas" en vb.net, ya está casi terminado pero me gustaría que también pudiera asociar los .txt, abrirlos y que el texto se muestre en el Textbox.

No me refiero a que lea y muestre un texto desde File > Open, únicamente necesito asociar los .txt con mi aplicación y que los abra por defecto (mostrándolo en el Textbox). ¿Alguna idea? Gracias.

Comment: ¿Creaste algún proyecto de instalación o estas publicando con ClickOnce u otro?

Comment: Aún no está creado el proyecto de instalación, pero no lo haré con ClickOnce.